# How to change selected index in Tabbar flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4, tabbar

How to change selected index in `Tabbar` from `ChildExistenceChangedEvent.CHILD_ADD` event?

This is the Flex 4.6 sdk code:

```
public function set selectedIndex(value:int):void
{
     // Bail if the index isn't changing.
     if (value == selectedIndex)
          return;
     // ignore, probably coming from tabbar
     if (addingChildren)
          return;
    .
    .
    .
}
```

So addingChildren is set to true and they ignore me, and they only change it after I finish executing my code.

I been trying to create a custom event and change it from there, but it's not working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, I am listening to UPDATE event and don't have this problem any more